# Sanitize sentence in php

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, sanitization

The title may sound odd, but im kind of trying to set up this preg_replace that takes care of messy writers for a textarea. It has to:

1. if there is an exclamation sign, there should not be another one in a row.
2. if there is a ., the comma wins and it has to be ,
3. when there is one+ spaces before a coma, it should be reduced to nothing.
4. the sentence cannot start or end with a comma.
5. there should never be more than 2 of the same letters joined together.
6. a space must be always present after a comma.

E.g.:

- ,My house, which is green., is nice!
- My  house..., which is green, is nice!!!
- My house ,which is  green,,, is nice!!

The end result should always be:

**My house, which is green, is nice!**

Is there an already built regex that takes care of this?

**Solution** check out [FakeRainBrigand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1074592/fakerainbrigand)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391958/sanitize-sentence-in-php/8392181#8392181) below!

Comment: I think you will need a regex here, str_replace will not be enough. I mean, what if there are 2 commas or three in a row. You may even need more than one regex for your rules

Comment: exactly, str_replace won't do the job. it is however a heave regex.

Comment: Does the solution need to allow for exceptions, such as will be needed when the text contains source code?

Comment: @MetaEd nope, it is just plain text for regular people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I might have to use this for my own sites... nice idea!

```
<?php

$text = 'My hooouse..., which is greeeeeen , is nice!!!  ,And pretty too...';

$pats = array(
'/([.!?]\s{2}),/', # Abc.  ,Def
'/\.+(,)/',  # ......,
'/(!)!+/',   # abc!!!!!!!!
'/\s+(,)/',  # abc   , def
'/([a-zA-Z])\1\1/', # greeeeeeen
'/,(?!\s)/'); 

$fixed = preg_replace($pats, '$1', $text);

echo $fixed;
echo "\n\n";

?>
```

And the 'modified' version of $text:  **"My house, which is green, is nice!  And pretty too."**

UPDATE: Here's the version that handles "abc,def" -> "abc, def".

```
<?php

$text = 'My hooouse..., which is greeeeeen ,is nice!!!  ,And pretty too...';

$pats = array(
'/([.!?]\s{2}),/', # Abc.  ,Def
'/\.+(,)/',        # ......,
'/(!)!+/',         # abc!!!!!!!!
'/\s+(,)/',        # abc   , def
'/([a-zA-Z])\1\1/');      # greeeeeeen

$fixed = preg_replace($pats, '$1', $text);
$really_fixed = preg_replace('/,(?!\s)/', ', ', $fixed);

echo $really_fixed;
echo "\n\n";
?>
```

I would think this is a bit slower since it's an additional function call.

Comment: I should note that the last pattern on there doesn't really work... you'd have to call a separate preg_replace for that one because the replacement of ```'$1'``` doesn't work.  If you think it's worth it, I can make the change.

Comment: Facebook needs this, as does almost every other site out there.

Comment: nice! what do you mean with "the last pattern on there doesn't really work"? can you make the change to know what you mean?

Comment: @andufo Note that this will remove 333333 as well. It will also remove comma without space, rather than adding a space after it etc.

Comment: @JamWaffles not only facebook, also Disqus and WP.

Comment: @FailedDev I see, also "My house ,which" becomes "My housewhich" instead of "My house, which" ;)

Comment: I fixed both of the problems.  The mistake was using ```.``` which means any character, when it should only be letters.  @andufo, by "last pattern" I was referring to the last element in the $pats array.

Comment: is this portable to javascript? i tried using the .replace(regex,string) way but it doesn't work exactly like preg_replace()

Comment: @andufo, it needs some modifications to work in JS.  Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvJUg/).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand you are the regex master. My resolution for january will be to master this art as well. Thanks once again!

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand hi again, the /\s+/g is also deleting new lines. I tried an approach that just takes care of extra new lines, didn't work: $('#translate_q').val($('#translate_q').val().replace(/\v+/g,''));

Comment: Replace the ```\s``` with ```[ ]``` for just spaces or ```[ \t]``` for spaces and tabs.  You don't technically need the square brackets for a space, but it makes it quite a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

```
 - $result = preg_replace('/!+/', '!', $subject);
 - $result = preg_replace('/\.*,/', ',', $subject);
 - $result = preg_replace('/\s+(?=,)/', '', $subject);
 - $result = preg_replace('/^,*|,*$/', '', $subject);
 - $result = preg_replace('/([a-z])\1+/i', '$1$1', $subject);
 - $result = preg_replace('/,(?!\s)/', ', ', $subject);
```

One by one matching to your rules :)

Comment: it does have some problems i wasn't aware of (using the $string from @FakeRainBrigand's example hehe)

Comment: @andufo Neither of the regexes are 100% correct. But I think my regex matched your specs :)