# RegEx to delete all double(or more) letter -> preg_replace

Tags: regex, preg-replace

Helo,

I've this RegEx to delete double letter on a string :

```
<?
$string = "Heeeeelloo";
echo preg_replace( '`(.*)\1`', '$1',$string)."\n";
```

The current result is : Heeelo

But i would like this result : Helo

What's wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: You should _definitely_ look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391958/sanitize-sentence-in-php) and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
preg_replace( '`(.)\1+`', '$1',$string);
```

Comment: Thanks 2min to anwser, i can not accept before 10 min ! but it work.